# Find entries within date-interval in sp_execute sql statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need some help with making a @query where I only get date-entries within a predefined interval. My full query is not shown here, as the rest of the query works fine. I only want to get data-entries which lies within a specific time-interval.

My time-interval are structured by FirstOfMonth And EndOfMonth for each month and year-entry, which means the data looks like this and the format is set to date:

[image]

I want to select the data which falls within the predefined interval specified by `@DateStart` and `@DateEnd`. As the query also needs to call column-names I've chosen to use this method. In my old query, I used the shown WHERE clause AS I want to catch all entries which falls within the first of the month in the selected `@DateStart` and the last of the month in the selected `@DateEnd`.

When I try to declare the variables as `datetime`, I get an error, saying I cannot use both `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and (`Datetime`) in the same @query. Is that correct understood as well?

```
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    ,@DateStart AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@DateEnd AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--  , + 4 Multiple Dynamically Declared 

SET @DateStart = '2016-03-23'
SET @DateEnd ='2019-01-31'

set @query = 
    '
    SELECT 
        * -- 4 Dynamically Declared Variables Here
        ,StartOfMonth
        ,EndOfMonth
    FROM TestData
        WHERE StartOfMonth >= DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(' + @DateStart + ',-1))
        AND EndOfMonth <= EOMONTH(' + @DateEnd + ')
    '
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
END
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql here anyway? From what you have posted there is no reason at all for this. And certainly don't make date variables as varchar.

Comment: Why are you injecting the dates instead of parametrising them? And, you certainly don't need 2GB to store a date and time value.

Comment: Even with `nvarchar(max)` your `WHERE` statement is wrong - `WHERE StartOfMonth >= DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(2016-03-23,-1)) AND EndOfMonth <= EOMONTH(2019-01-31)`. Use parameters in your dynamic statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using dynamic sql. You could eliminate that complexity and just run a parameterized query. Something like this.

```
SELECT 
    * -- Multiple Declared Text Variables Here
    ,StartOfMonth
    ,EndOfMonth
FROM TestData
WHERE StartOfMonth >= DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@DateStart,-1))
    AND EndOfMonth <= EOMONTH(@DateEnd)
```

Or if for some reason that isn't clear from what you posted you really do need dynamic sql you should parameterize it. That would end up something like this.

```
set @query = 
    N'
    SELECT 
        * -- Multiple Declared Text Variables Here
        ,StartOfMonth
        ,EndOfMonth
    FROM TestData
        WHERE StartOfMonth >= DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@Date_Start,-1))
        AND EndOfMonth <= EOMONTH(@Date_End)
    '
EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@Date_Start date, @Date_End date', @Date_Start = @DateStart, @Date_End = @DateEnd
```